# Shiny: Event registering/priority for javascript select()

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

In my shiny app I have a `textInput` which gets updated via USB QR-Code-scanner. From my testing, this works as if one would <s>copy-paste</s> *type* text very fast into the `textInput` every time a code is scanned. When a code is scanned I would like that text to replace the existing text, so that the rest of the app updates immediately, without clicking any buttons or manually having to delete the text every time.

I tried doing this with `shinyjs` and some JavaScript using the `select()` function: The idea being, if the `textInput` is always selected, any new added text would just overwrite the old one.

This works great, for one exception: If the same code is scanned twice, the `observeEvent` doesn't fire, the text is unselected, and the cycle breaks. I had a similar problem with shiny not registering an event when the same button is clicked twice, and this was solvable using `{priority: 'event'}` However, I can't seem to get this approach to work with the `select()` function.

MRE:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)

js_select <- '
shinyjs.select = function(e) {
  $("#some_input").select();
}'

ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs(text = js_select, functions = "select"),
    fluidRow(
      textInput("some_input","Enter Some Input"),
      br(),
      textOutput("some_output")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  js$select()
  
  observeEvent(input$some_input,{
    js$select()
  })
  
  output$some_output <- renderText(input$some_input)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: What `select("e")` is supposed to do?

Comment: Leftover from the original version where there was a variable telling which input to select. Edited it out for clarity.

Comment: I don't understand. `.select()` does nothing on a text input. Why don't you use `updateTextInput`?

Comment: It selects/highlights the text in the input field as if you'd mark it with the mouse. This means that any new input from the scanner is not added to the text input (which would happen if I just focused on it with `.focus()`), but replaces it instead.

Comment: I don't know anything about QR code scanning, but can't you catch an event when you scan?

Answer (score 1):

For the QR code scanning I don't know but for the problem you describe you can use the `paste` event:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

js <- '
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#some_input").on("paste", function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {$this.select();});
  });
});
'

ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js))),
    
    fluidRow(
      textInput("some_input", "Enter Some Input"),
      br(),
      textOutput("some_output")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  output$some_output <- renderText(input$some_input)
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works under the conditions I originally asked, especially when setting the focus on the text input at startup. Sadly my assumption about the Scanner was wrong since it doesn't trigger a `paste` event - instead it actually behaves as if a human user was typing very fast on a keyboard. A critical mistake on my part.
Nonetheless, the `setTimeout` function is a great addition for making my current app much less inconvenient when users want to enter IDs manually.